# Android studio 3 unable to connect Tor proxy

Tags: android-studio

android studio is unable to connect Tor proxy.

```
host : 127.0.0.1
port : 9150
```

when i click check connection nothing happens!
Tor web browser works fine.
in previous AndroidStudio versions i had no problem.

so what to do?! is listener port correct?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `proxychain` , `torify` or `torsocks`
before using these codes make sure you run `tor-browser` in desktop or `tor` in terminal.
use code like this(linux):
`torsocks -P 9150 [android-studio-location]/bin/studio.sh`
or
`torify [android-studio-location]/bin/studio.sh`
`proxychain [android-studio-location]/bin/studio.sh`

for windows try (socks):
 
`host: localhost
port: 9150`

i hope it works for you.
windows tested with AS v2.
linux tested with AS v3.

Answer (score -5):

I had exactly the same problem. I was using android studio 3.0.

then i installed android studio 2.3 and it is working now again.